# Find the disc of convergence of the power series (real/complex analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find the disc of convergence:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z-3)^{n}}{n(n+1}$$

I have tried geometic series, ratio test, root test... but I seem to get stuck each time. What would be your thought on the best test to use?

Comment: The series converges whenever $|z-3|\le 1$ since $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|z-3|^{n+1}}{|z-3|^n}\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=|z-3|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio or root test *does* work, but would only be good enough to determine the radius of convergence. No conclusion can be drawn on convergence right at the circle of convergence. In the present problem we can make straightforward estimates.

For any $|z-3|>1$ the terms diverge so the series does not converge. For any $|z-3|\leqslant 1$ we can use the convergent majorant $|(z-3)^n/n/(n+1)| \leqslant 1/n^2$. So the radius of convergence is $1$, while the disc of convergence $|z-3|\leqslant 1$ includes the circle of convergence.